# Git:push from branch caused unwanted files to be committed

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-push

I am stuck with a weird problem which i dont seem to understand. I had two local git branches which both pointed to the same remote. Local branches are **master** and **tenant** and i have the following config in **.git** of my ws

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@egitrepo:project.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "tenant"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

I did this so i can do **git pull** easily on both the branches without specifying the remote on the command line.

I am working on the **tenant** branch while my **master** branch was not updated and old. I made changes in my **tenant** branch, did **git pull** and tried to **push** the changes to remote.

Doing **git push** from the **tenant** branch gave me the fast-forward error.

```
To git@egitrepo:milkyway.git
    ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'git@egitrepo:milkyway.git'
```

At this point, i looked around and found that this was due to **git push** trying to push all my local branches to the remote i.e both my **tenant** and **master**(non-updated).

I found a solution to this problem by setting

```
 git config --global push.default upstream
```

which tells git to push only the current branch to its matching upsteam branch. This solved my problem and my push from **tenant** branch went successful.

Now comes the problem part, when i looked at the commit history by using  **git diff** to see my commit, i found a number of other files which SHOULD NOT have been a part of the commit. I had added only 8 files for commit and looked at **git status** very carefully before doing the commit and it showed only the 8 correct files under the **changes to be commited section**.

How did all those other files went into my commit? Were they added from the **master** as part of the first failed **git push** i tried? I say this because these are some of the files i changed in the **master** branch. Why did git not show them to me in the correct section of git status.Can anybody explain this? Also how can i revert?

Comment: When you first start using git, sometimes a bad habit develops, and you unwittingly do `git add .` or `git -am 'commit message'`.  Did this happen to you?

Comment: Are these unexpect files in the same commit you pushed to origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can review the commit history and reflog to determine what happend.

Use git-reflog and I bet you will see a merge from master to tenant.